# question of sum of independent uniform random variables

Tags: probability

Let U be uniform on (0,1) and V has density $ f_V(v)=2(1-v)$ for (0,1).
To get the distribution of Z=U+V, we had to calculate two cases, for 0< z < 1 and 1 < z < 2. For the second case, the solution is
$$ P(U+V\le z) =\int_0^{z-1}\int_0^12(1-y)dxdy \space+\int_{z-1}^1\int_0^{z-y}2(1-y)dxdy$$.

I don't understand how to derive this solution, I thought that it might mean $P(U\le z-Y|Y\le z-1)P(Y\le z-1) + P(U\le z-Y|Y \le z-1|Y> z-1)P(Y> z-1). $ But how do the integrals follow and why .

Comment: Why introduce conditionings where there are none and they are not needed? This could only complicate things, right?

Answer (score 0):

The pdf of $Z$ is given by convolving the pdf of $U$ and $V$:
$$\begin{align}
f_U(u)&=1_{\{0\le u\le 1\}}\\[10pt]
f_V(v)&=2(1-v)1_{\{0\le v\le 1\}}\\[10pt]
f_Z(z)&=f_U(u)\star f_V(v)\\[10pt]
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_V(\tau)f_U(z-\tau)d\tau\\[10pt]
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2(1-\tau)1_{\{0\le \tau\le 1\}}\cdot 1_{\{0\le z-\tau\le 1\}}d\tau\\[10pt]
&=1_{\{0\le z<1\}}\cdot\int_{0}^{z}2(1-\tau)d\tau + 1_{\{1\le z<2\}}\cdot\int_{z-1}^{1}2(1-\tau)d\tau\\[10pt]
&=\left(2z-z^2\right)1_{\{0\le z<1\}}+(z^2-4z+4)1_{\{1\le z<2\}}
\end{align}$$
Or simply
$$f_Z(z)=\begin{cases}
z(2-z),& 0\le z<1\\
(z-2)^2,& 1\le z<2
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I am lost, what does this line mean $ 1_{\{0\le z<1\}}\cdot\int_{0}^{z}2(1-\tau)d\tau + 1_{\{1\le z<2\}}\cdot\int_{z-1}^{1}2(1-\tau)d\tau$

Comment: $$1_{\{\text{condition}\}}=\begin{cases}1,& \text{condition holds}\\0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$